# Excel VBA- Lookup cell to paste value to

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro that inserts a value into a specific cell of table by looking up a row value and looking up a column value and using that to determine the cell to paste to. I am quite new to VBA so I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

This is what I have so far:

```
Name=Sheets("Input").Range("C5")
Week=Sheets("Input").Range("C19")
copyCell=Sheets("Input").Range("C18")

pasteCell = Application.Index(Sheets("Resources").Range("B2:AZ50"),Application.Match(Week,Sheets("Resources").Range("A2:A50"),0),Application.Match(Name,Sheets("Resources").Range("B1:AZ1"),0))

copyCell.Copy
pasteCell.PasteSpecial PasteValues
```

I keep getting a runtime error object required but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong...

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

This  is the table which the cell is being pasted too (this table is not the real table just an example so as to hide the names in the table but it looks exactly the same except that the real table starts on the first row).

[image]

And this is the input page:

[image]

Note: I have since put in more code surrounding the week variable:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Input").Range("C19")) = 0 Then
Week = Sheets("Input").Range("C20").Value
Else
Week = Sheets("Input").Range("C19").Value
End If
```

Very much appreciate the help you guys are giving!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing more of your code, I assume you have declared `copyCell` and `pasteCell` as Type `Variant` (if it is not declared, it *is* type `Variant`).

This will raise the error you describe.

Resolve it by properly declaring your variables, and using the `Set` keyword when assigning object variables.

Additionally, failing to declare `Name` and `Week` will raise the `424 Object Required` error, too.  They should be `String` data type, and assigned using the range `.Value` method.  This error will persist, without more revision to your code, if either of the match functions returns an error (match not found).

I think this will work:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Name As String
Dim Week As Long
Dim copyCell As Range
Dim pasteCell As Range

Name = Sheets("Input").Range("C5").Value
Week = CLng(DateValue(Sheets("Input").Range("C19").Value))
Set copyCell = Sheets("Input").Range("C18")

If Not IsError(Application.Match(Week, Sheets("Resources").Range("A2:A50"), 0)) And _
    Not IsError(Application.Match(Name, Sheets("Resources").Range("B1:AZ1"), 0)) Then

    Set pasteCell = Application.Index(Sheets("Resources").Range("B2:AZ50"), _
        Application.Match(Week, Sheets("Resources").Range("A2:A50"), 0), _
        Application.Match(Name, Sheets("Resources").Range("B1:AZ1"), 0))

    copyCell.Copy
    pasteCell.PasteSpecial PasteValues
Else:
    MsgBox Name & " and/or " & Week & " not found!", vbInformation
End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATED**

Excel doesn't always know what to do with date values. that was the case here. On the worksheet, a date value is stored as a long integer. In the macro, we're referring to it as a string, which can raise several errors including '1004' (unable to match).

I made a revision to the code above, `Dim Week as Long` and then changed the assignment to ensure the value is interpreted as a `Date` from the worksheet, and then as a `Long` integer when assigned to this variable:

```
Week = CLng(DateValue(Sheets("Input").Range("C19").Value))
```

Now, this may not be foolproof if your dates aren't all actually dates (google it...) but this actually happens pretty often some dates are entered as dates (numbers formatted as date) and others are entered as string literals. If that is the case, the `Week` value should still be handled properly, but the lookup range also should be formatted the same way to avoid potential errors again.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems to be working up until the IF Not IsError part where it keeps telling me that the name and week can't be found even though I am sure that they are there (I've checked for spaces and made sure that the lookup value and the values in the table header and columns are the same)

Comment: If you do `Debug.Print Application.Match(Week, Sheets("Resources").Range("A2:A50"), 0))` and `Debug.Print Application.Match(Name, Sheets("Resources").Range("B1:AZ1"), 0)` what does it tell you?

Comment: A screenshot of what the data in Column A and Row 1 looks like would help.

Comment: I can't seem to upload a picture as I don't have enough reputation :S
Basically it has names going across the top row from B1:AZ1 and dates going from A2:A50.

Comment: Where would I put Debug.Print Application.Match(Week, Sheets("Resources").Range("A2:A50"), 0)? In the macro code? It just seems to run through the same without doing anything.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really have the time to teach you how to debug your code. Use F8 to step through it, and examine the values of the variables step by step.  You can put the `Debug` statements after the `Set copyCell = ...` line.

Comment: You say that you have names going across B1:AZ1, i.e you have the first row of your input sheet (except cell A1) with names, right? In your code, you are assigning the variable 'name' with value in C5 (5th row, 3rd column). What is the value in c5? Same question with the week variable also. Always show a screenshot/pseudo data in your question to get more responses. It really helps.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. I can't actually post pictures because I'm not allowed to post pictures until I have a certain level of 'reputation'. The value of C5 is the name to lookup, the idea of the code is to copy the cell c18 in the input sheet and paste it into the resources sheet into the cell which is in the column corresponding to c5 and the row corresponding to c19.

Comment: If you can upload a picture to imgur.com, I can edit your post to include the screenshot since I have sufficient rep to edit others' posts.

Comment: Added the links at the end of the original post.

Comment: ok i've seen this before. Excel doesn't always know how to interpret date values. See revision above.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It works! Would upvote your answer...but it won't let me.

Comment: no need to upvote it, you've already approved it :) glad I could help.